# What are the arguments for the promise returned by $interval in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, setinterval, angular-promise

I am using Angularjs 1.4. Suppose I have a promise returned by $interval.

```
var promise = $interval(function () {
}, 1000);
```

I want to make use of this promise.

```
promise.then(???)
```

However, I am at a loss what parameters are available for this returned promise. I am not able to find the answer in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

What are the parameters for this returned promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters for the `then` method of a promise are:

```
then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)
```

For more information, [see the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (find: "the promise api")

---

The callbacks that are used, and how they are called, will depend on the function that is provide you with the promise object. In the case of `$interval` the callbacks will get called as follows:

`successCallback`: called when the interval function completes (assuming it is set to expire)

`errorCallback`: called in the event of an error

`notifyCallback`: called with each tick of the interval timer

**Example**

```
var promise = $interval(function () 
  {
  }, 1000, 10);

promise.then(function (){
    //On Success: called after 10 seconds (10 x 1000ms).
}, function (){
    //On Error: called when an error occurs.
}, function (){
    //On Notify: called every second (1000ms).
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Is this a standard for all promises returned in AngularJS?

Comment: @user768421: see updated answer for more information. But yes, the `then` parameters are standard for all promise objects, but they may get called differently depending on the function that provided it to you

Answer (score 2):

It's said in [**the docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval):

> This promise will be **notified** upon each tick of the interval, and will
>   be **resolved** after `count` iterations, or run indefinitely if `count` is
>   not defined. The value of the notification will be the number of
>   iterations that have run.

So you have to define a *notifyCallback* param for `then` method to process it; the param of this callback will be the number of iterations.

Comment: Is this `notifyCallback()` the `successCallback()` in musefan's answer?

Comment: No, `successCallback` is called only when a promise is resolved. Check [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcL0IZShk2B0lIqMqk1b?p=preview) with three callbacks passed into `.then`; you'll see that only the third one is called at each step.